# Condition based on environment variable existance

Tags: tcl

Is it right to use the following condition based on environment variables. Or there is better way?

Example:

```
# Both environment variables must exist
if {expr [eval {info exists env(VARIABLE_1)}] && [eval {info exists env(VARIABLE_2)}]} {
    # true: do something 
} else {
    # false: do something different
}
```

Comment: Avoid `eval` as much as possible. If you think you need it, you probably need to simplify what you're trying to do.

Comment: Note also that the `if` conditional expression is already handled by `expr` so calling `expr` explicitly is redundant.

Comment: Just trying to remember the last time I needed `eval` since Tcl 8.5 became production-ready. I'm sure there must've been something — some of my code is really quite tricky! — but I can't think of it right now…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `info` alone should work:

```
# Both environment variables must exist
if {[info exists env(VARIABLE_1)] && [info exists env(VARIABLE_2)]} {
    # true: do something 
} else {
    # false: do something different
}
```

Since `info` returns a boolean, `if` handles it fine and you don't neet `expr`. The above works on my machine.